# React native drag and drop position football training

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, drag-and-drop

[image]

I have such a thing, the formations are so declared:

4-4-2:

```
[
[{}]//1
[{},{},{},{}...],//4
[{},{},{},{}...],//4
[{},{}...]//2
]
```

So I do two nested cycles, one to scroll the rows from the door to the midfield (number of arrays inside the main array), and one to scroll through each individual player per row (number of obj within the single array row).
So far it works properly, I repeat this thing both for the home team and the away team is working properly.

The problem is that I would like to apply the drap and drop.
What I would like to do is that initially the positions of the players are from assigned training, to then be able to move every single player in the field, even in the opposing part of the field.

Any advice on how I could do this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

export default class FootballField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      home: props.home,
      away: props.away,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('./images/footballfield.png')}
          style={{
            width: null,
            height: null,
            flex: 1,
          }}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.45)', flex: 1 }}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(204, 70, 43, 0)',
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={[
                    styles.text,
                    {
                      marginLeft: 20,
                    },
                  ]}>
                  {this.state.home.module}
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={[
                    styles.text,
                    {
                      position: 'absolute',
                      right: 20,
                    },
                  ]}>
                  {this.state.home.name}
                </Text>
              </View>

              {this.state.home.team.map((data, i) => (
                <View style={styles.rowHome}>
                  {data.map((d, j) => (
                    <View style={styles.el}>
                      <View
                        style={{
                          flexDirection: 'row',
                        }}>
                        {this.state.home.home_team_events.map(
                          (el, z) =>
                            d.name == el.player &&
                            el.type_of_event == 'yellow-card' && (
                              <Image
                                source={require('./imagess/card-yellow.png')}
                                style={{
                                  width: 12,
                                  height: 15,
                                  position: 'absolute',
                                  left: -12,
                                }}
                              />
                            )
                        )}
                        {this.state.home.home_team_events.map(
                          (el, z) =>
                            d.name == el.player &&
                            el.type_of_event == 'red-card' && (
                              <Image
                                source={require('./images/card-red.png')}
                                style={{
                                  width: 12,
                                  height: 15,
                                  position: 'absolute',
                                  left: -12,
                                }}
                              />
                            )
                        )}
                        <View style={styles.playHome}>
                          <Text style={styles.text}>{d.number}</Text>
                        </View>
                        {this.state.home.home_team_events.map(
                          (el, z) =>
                            d.name == el.player &&
                            el.type_of_event == 'substitution-in' && (
                              <Image
                                source={require('./images/refresh.png')}
                                style={{
                                  width: 12,
                                  height: 12,
                                  position: 'absolute',
                                  right: -14,
                                }}
                              />
                            )
                        )}
                      </View>
                      <Text style={styles.text}>{d.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                  ))}
                </View>
              ))}
            </View>

            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(43, 99, 204, 0)',
                paddingTop: 55,
              }}>
              {this.state.away.team.reverse().map((data, i) => (
                <View style={styles.rowAway}>
                  {data.map((d, j) => (
                    <View style={styles.el}>
                      <Text style={styles.text}>{d.name}</Text>
                      <View
                        style={{
                          flexDirection: 'row',
                        }}>
                        {this.state.away.away_team_events.map(
                          (el, z) =>
                            d.name == el.player &&
                            el.type_of_event == 'yellow-card' && (
                              <Image
                                source={require('./images/card-yellow.png')}
                                style={{
                                  width: 12,
                                  height: 15,
                                  position: 'absolute',
                                  left: -12,
                                }}
                              />
                            )
                        )}
                        {this.state.away.away_team_events.map(
                          (el, z) =>
                            d.name == el.player &&
                            el.type_of_event == 'red-card' && (
                              <Image
                                source={require('./images/card-red.png')}
                                style={{
                                  width: 12,
                                  height: 15,
                                  position: 'absolute',
                                  left: -12,
                                }}
                              />
                            )
                        )}
                        <View style={styles.playAway}>
                          <Text style={styles.text}>{d.number}</Text>
                        </View>
                        {this.state.away.away_team_events.map(
                          (el, z) =>
                            d.name == el.player &&
                            el.type_of_event == 'substitution-in' && (
                              <Image
                                source={require('./images/refresh.png')}
                                style={{
                                  width: 12,
                                  height: 12,
                                  position: 'absolute',
                                  right: -14,
                                }}
                              />
                            )
                        )}
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  ))}
                </View>
              ))}

              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={[
                    styles.text,
                    {
                      marginLeft: 20,
                    },
                  ]}>
                  {this.state.away.module}
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={[
                    styles.text,
                    {
                      position: 'absolute',
                      right: 20,
                    },
                  ]}>
                  {this.state.away.name}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  rowHome: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  rowAway: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  el: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  playHome: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 15,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'rgb(244, 67, 54)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(244, 67, 54,0.5)',
  },
  playAway: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 15,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'rgb(3, 169, 244)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(3, 169, 244,0.5)',
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#fff',
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
    textShadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    textShadowRadius: 1,
    fontSize: 15,
  },
});
```

Comment: Did you make progress on this? I'm curious about Javascript and sports simulation. Anyhow, do you intend that after the user drag-drops a player (anywhere), the code would automatically move the other players while maintaining formations (relatively)?